# Accessing Data Points Used in Specific Folds of GridSearchCV with MLPRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I am currently using GridSearchCV and Pipeline from scikit-learn for hyperparameter tuning. My estimator is GradientBoostingRegressor. During the cross-validation process, I encountered a situation where one of the models' folds produced a negative score, while all the other folds of this model seem to be acceptable. This inconsistency has led me to suspect potential issues within the data for that particular fold.

To investigate further, I'd like to access the information about which data points were used in that specific fold with the negative score. How can I do this? Is there a way to identify and retrieve the data points associated with a particular fold when using GridSearchCV?

Here is a minimal example:

```
XGBoost_param_grid = {"learning_rate": [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5],
                      "n_estimators": [10, 100, 500, 1000],
                      "max_depth": [3, 10, None],
                      "max_features": ["sqrt", "log2", None]}
gs_obj = GridSearchCV(estimator=GradientBoostingRegressor(), cv=5)
pipeline = Pipeline([("scaler", MinMaxScaler()), ("model", gs_obj)])

pipeline.fit(X, y)
```

Let's say, that the best model has following scores (r2) per fold:

fold 0: 0.5
fold 1: 0.4
fold 2: 0.7
fold 3: 0.2
fold 4: - 0.7

Now i want to know what samples are in these folds (especially in fold 4).

**EDIT:** It is possible by providing a sklearn.model_selection.KFold object as cv-argument value of GridSearchCV. In that way, the split indices of the KFold object are used and can be accessed.

What if i want to know the prediction value made for every sample in the test fold? How can i access these values?